# visual c++ /MANIFESTUAC linker option doesn't work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

Why this linker flag doesn't work I tried it many times with different syntaxes and no one worked

```
cl /MT /GS- exam.cpp /link /MANIFESTUAC:level=\'requireAdministrator\'
```

and this :

```
cl /MT /GS- exam.cpp /link /MANIFESTUAC:level=requireAdministrator
```

and also this :

```
cl /MT /GS- exam.cpp /link /MANIFESTUAC:"level=requireAdministrator uiAccess=false"
```

the compiled exe doesn't pop up the uac window when I execute it

Comment: requireAdministrator: 'The application will run with administrator permissions. The user who starts the application must be a member of the Administrators group. If the opening process is not running with administrative permissions, the system will prompt for credentials.' Maybe the opening process is already an adminstrator?

Comment: no it isn't , I checked the file with resource hacker and didn't find a manifest resource in the file

Answer (score 2):

I got it from the linker command line in visual studio
I had to add this flag

```
/MANIFEST
```

then the /MANIFESTUAC will be written like this :

```
/MANIFESTUAC:"level='requireAdministrator' uiAccess='false'"
```